# Elementary Hera is slow on older Mac, Puppy 8.0 is fast as is Mac OS. Is there something I can do (that is not too technical)?

Tags: release-hera

EOS Hera on Mac Pro 1,1, mostly everthing works except it doesn't save monitor settings and is quite slow compare to Mac OS and Puppy/Linux(which I am posting from)

Comment: I'm also looking for any faster way to use eOS on MacBookAir2,1. So far, I found is to replace window manager with openbox instead of gala.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrZ9uhTPJkk

Answer (score 0):

You can install other desktop environment (e.g. JWM, IceWM, or Fluxbox).
Doing so allows you to choose your session before you login by pressing gear icon next to the password text field.[image: DE selection at logon]

I've tried with fluxbox and this works great so far with about 250Mb memory consumption when idle.